# Type Ellipse not found in xmlns in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin App, I'm trying to use `Ellipse` in xml, but it returned the error:

> Type Ellipse not found in xmlns `http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms`

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/ellipse

**Page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Start" >

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <Ellipse Fill="Red"
                WidthRequest="150"
                HeightRequest="50"
                HorizontalOptions="Start" />

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Which Forms version are you using? Also, have you enabled the Experimental flag?

Comment: @MihailDuchev by Form version u mean ```xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"``` ??

Comment: no, Experimental flag isn't enabled..

Comment: I mean the Xamarin.Forms version. Also, you should enable the Experimental flag, since shapes are still in experimental phase.

Comment: @MihailDuchev The experimental flag `ShapesExperimental` is not required starting from **4.8.0.1534** and higher.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms v4.8.0.1560 is installed..

Comment: yes, installed everywhere... okay.. I'll try and then update

Comment: clean the solution, close, reopen and rebuild it and still not working

Comment: you will have to set the flags in App.cs file
public App()
{
    Device.SetFlags(new[] {"Shapes_Experimental", "Brush_Experimental"});
    InitializeComponent()
}

Comment: @IngmarBergman I have made this as answer. If the reply is helpful, Please accept it as answer and upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set the flags in App.cs file

```
public App() 
{ 
     Device.SetFlags(new[] {"Shapes_Experimental", "Brush_Experimental"}); 
     InitializeComponent() 
}
```